# EAV Database Query

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

irst of all thank you for your time...

I have created a EAV database with 3 tables

```
**db_main**

data_id, data_name

**db_integer**

data_id, field_id, data_value

**db_imgs**

img_id, img_path
```

I use this query to get data from `db_integer` for fields (8), `img_id` is the serial of the image.

For example:

```
db_main {1, testing}
db_integer {1, 9, 1}
db_imgs {1, 'path'}
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  data_name,
        MAX( IF(db_intteger.field_id = 9,db_integer.int_value, NULL) ) as img_id
  FROM  db_main_tbl
    LEFT JOIN db_integer USING (data_id)
  GROUP BY db_main.data_id
```

But i can't take the path of the image from the third table... any ideas? I want the images to be in a different table so i can reuse them...

i want to get {1(data_id),9(field_id),'img_path'}

Comment: Am I correct in saying that in `db_integer`, if the `field_id` is 8 or 9, then the `data_value` will indicate the `img_id` in the `db_imgs` table?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: @MartinParkin i edited my post... Yes i will get the img_id but if i use ing_id in a where syntax i get an unknown field....